# How to speed up Excel formula with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, performance, excel-formula

I’d like to count how many times a certain company is audited according to a certain standard. If a company XYZ in a column F is audited according to a certain standard in a column C more than 3 times, it should count as 3. If this company is audited 3 times or less, it should count as it is.

Here is the example (column H is the desired result):

[image]

I use the following formula:

`=IF(OR(C2<>C1,F2<>F1),MIN(3,COUNTIFS(C$2:C$60000,C2,F$2:F$60000,F2)),"")`

However, it takes over 30 minutes, when I drag this formula in all 60,000 rows. Is there a way to speed it up? Maybe with a VBA code? Or will it take the same time and doesn't worth it?

Any feedback is highly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Usually VBA is not faster because it does not support multi-threading while formulas can be calculated in multiple threads. In generaly you can only say if one or the other is faster if you tried it and measured the time. There is no general answer.

Comment: I have tried this one, however it is as slow as the previous one:
 `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($F$2:F2=F2)*($C$2:C2=C2))=1,MIN(3,COUNTIFS($F$2:$F$60000,F2,$C$2:$C$60000,C2)),"")`

Comment: all the `*IFS` formula will be a problem with large of  a data set.  It would best in vba.  Load the two columns into variant arrays.  Loop them and create a concatenated key in a dictionary and add 1 to the value till it hits 3.  Then loop again to create the output.  it will be a lot quicker.

Comment: Make sure your data is sorted on C then F in ascending order then try this formula: `=IF(OR(C2<>C1,F2<>F1),MIN(3,MATCH(C2&"Z",INDEX(C:C,ROW()):C60000),MATCH(F2&"Z",INDEX(F:F,ROW()):F60000)),"")`

Comment: @Scott Craner Thank you! It works MUCH faster!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test your speed.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngDB As Range, vDB As Variant
    Dim s1, s2
    Dim r As Long, i As Long
    Dim k As Long, n As Long
    
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Set rngDB = Ws.UsedRange.Offset(1)
    vDB = rngDB
    
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    s1 = vDB(1, 3)
    s2 = vDB(1, 6)
    
    k = 1
    For i = 1 To r
        If vDB(i, 3) = s1 And vDB(i, 6) = s2 Then
            n = n + 1
        Else
            vDB(k, 8) = WorksheetFunction.Min(3, n)
            k = i
            n = 1
            s1 = vDB(i, 3)
            s2 = vDB(i, 6)
        End If
    Next i
    rngDB = vDB
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately I receive the error message "index out of range" when the code reaches `vDB(k, 8) = WorksheetFunction.Min(3, n)`

Comment: @Sam,Is "Result" recorded in column H, row 1?

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I don't know why, but it works now like magic! Thank you again, dear Dy.Lee, for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Usually VBA is not faster because it does not support multi-threading while formulas can be calculated in multiple threads. In generaly you can only say if one or the other is faster if you tried it and measured the time. There is no general answer.

But your formula has one issue. For each row it calculates the `countifs` through the entire data of 60000 rows. So it goes 60000 times through 60000 rows to do an `if`. That can never be fast.

What I would do is:

1. Sort the data by first `Company` and second `Standard`.
2. With sorted data (using VBA) you don't need to go through your data 60000 times but only one time. Which then would be much quicker than this formula (especially when using arrays). In VBA you can take advantage of the sorting to improve runtime while the formula will also work on unsorted data.

You would need to check how fast this really is:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CalcAmountsOnSortedData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'define sheet
    
    Dim LastRow As Long 'find last used row in column F
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'read data into arrays for fast processing
    Dim DataStandard() As Variant
    DataStandard = ws.Range("C1", "C" & LastRow)
    
    Dim DataCompany() As Variant
    DataCompany = ws.Range("F1", "F" & LastRow)
    
    Dim DataOutput() As Variant
    DataOutput = ws.Range("H1", "H" & LastRow)
    
    Dim StartRow As Long
    StartRow = 2 'because of header
    Dim Sum As Long
    
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 2 To LastRow 'loop through all rows
        Sum = Sum + 1 'one more of the same company/standard
        
        If iRow = LastRow Then
            'if last row then write sum
            DataOutput(StartRow, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Max(3, Sum)
        ElseIf DataStandard(iRow, 1) <> DataStandard(iRow + 1, 1) Or DataCompany(iRow, 1) <> DataCompany(iRow + 1, 1) Then
            'if standard or company changed then write sum
            DataOutput(StartRow, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Max(3, Sum)
            'reset for next company/standard counting
            Sum = 0
            StartRow = iRow + 1
        End If
    Next iRow
    
    'write data from array back to cells
    ws.Range("H1", "H" & LastRow) = DataOutput
End Sub
```

The code only works if data was sorted on Company and Standard before you run teh code.

Comment: Good explanations enrich any post with fine code, and they actually do :+)

Answer (score -3):

Something like this should do the trick.  Change to suit your needs.

```
Sub MyMacro()
    Range("H2:H60000").Formula = _
    "=IF(OR(RC[-5]<>R[-1]C[-5],RC[-2]<>R[-1]C[-2]),MIN(3,COUNTIFS(R2C[-5]:R60000C[-5],RC[-5],R2C[-2]:R60000C[-2],RC[-2])),"""")"
End Sub
```

Comment: 1. Your formula needs to be in `""` 2. this will not be any quicker than what the OP has.

Comment: Also Excel has more than `65536` rows you should never hard code this. `Rows.Count` gives you the correct amount of rows.

Comment: That was a copy/paste mistake.  I modified/simplified the code.  Obviously, you can make the ranges dynamic.  I'll leave it to the OP to do that.  The code finishes in about 60 seconds on my machine.